# Will a 2008 g35 w/auto go in 2006 g35

Tags: engine, infiniti, part-interchange, g35

I have complete 2008 to install in 2006. Will it work if using cam and wiring harness for motor and trans.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Physically it would fit, but you'd either have to have your ECU tuned for the new engine or use the ECU out of the 2008. Depending on what type of G35 it came out of, it has different HP/TQ levels. The 2008 sedan was a VQ35HR with 306HP/268TQ and the coupe was a VQ35DE with 298HP/270TQ. Your 2006 should have the VQ35DE, but the HP/TQ ratings are completely different. And then it depends on if it was a coupe/sedan or manual/auto transmission. It appears that even some of the later 2008's came with a VQ37VHR which was a 3.7L engine.

Comment: Its an automatic and so is my 06 I was going to change motor and harness and cam .was wondering she rather the push button starter on 08 was in end or back